# Which URL is best

Tags: subdomain, url-rewriting, server

We are in the process of creating landing pages whose contents will be living in the server whose directory houses `mylove.example.com`.  The URL will be `mylove.example.com` but for marketing purposes, we want to point to a friendly marketing URL.

Would the solution be to point the URL to the root domain `www.example.com/mylove` which is a live site whose directory lives on a different server? This also means the contents for the marketing-friendly URL would live on `mylove.mylive.example`.

The thought behind this would help these pages rank better since there is domain authority with `www.example.com`.

Will, there be SEO repercussions for forcing URLs with the `mylove.example.com` to be pointed to `www.mylove.example` even though the contents do not live on the same server as `www.mylove.example`?

Will Google be able to crawl contents for `mylove.example.com` and `example.com`? The pages are not permanently moving. We are wanting to leverage domain authority without having to create a whole new domain name.

Comment: you mention `mylove.mylive.example` once, but I have no idea what that is as it doesn't relate to the other URLs you mention at all.

Comment: When you say "point the URL", how are you intending to do that?   DNS entries can't point to subdirectories, so you must be considering a redirect, frameset, or reverse proxy.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to type in as much as I could. In a nutshell, we have subdomain that is on a different physical server which means it's not hosted on the same server as the domain.  What are the options to point the subdomain as a subfolder within the domain? No not necessarily,  pointing using the DNS entries.

Comment: This is answered by the duplicate questions here.  You can use a reverse proxy to put content from a different server on the subdirectory.  However, it can be slow, so I only recommend doing that if the two servers are on the same local area network (very fast connection between them).    Having a subdomain isn't significantly worse for SEO, so when two servers are involved, I recommend sticking with the subdomain.